# How can I write this jQuery code using several selectors and events more compactly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use some JavaScript to change some styles while hovering certain elements. Since this happens around six times on my landingpage, I copied this six times and changed the respective class.

But it seems really messy to me and I wonder if there is a more compact and elegant way to write? I am not talking about JavaScript compression.

```
$(function() {
  // 1. Main
  $('.main1').hover(function() {
    $('.main1').css('color', '#0000d2');
    $('.main1 img').css('mix-blend-mode', 'luminosity');
  }, function() {
    $('.main1').css('color', '');
    $('.main1 img').css('mix-blend-mode', '');
  });

  // 2. Main
  $('.main2').hover(function() {
    $('.main2').css('color', '#0000d2');
    $('.main2 img').css('mix-blend-mode', 'luminosity');
  }, function() {
    $('.main2').css('color', '');
    $('.main2 img').css('mix-blend-mode', '');
  });

  // 3. Main
  $('.main3').hover(function() {
    $('.main3').css('color', '#0000d2');
    $('.main3 img').css('mix-blend-mode', 'luminosity');
  }, function() {
    $('.main3').css('color', '');
    $('.main3 img').css('mix-blend-mode', '');
  });

  // 1. Sub
  $('.sub1').hover(function() {
    $('.sub1').css('color', '#0000d2');
    $('.sub1 img').css('mix-blend-mode', 'luminosity');
  }, function() {
    $('.sub1').css('color', '');
    $('.sub1 img').css('mix-blend-mode', '');
  });

  // 2. Sub
  $('.sub2').hover(function() {
    $('.sub2').css('color', '#0000d2');
    $('.sub2 img').css('mix-blend-mode', 'luminosity');
  }, function() {
    $('.sub2').css('color', '');
    $('.sub2 img').css('mix-blend-mode', '');
  });

  // 3. Sub
  $('.sub3').hover(function() {
    $('.sub3').css('color', '#0000d2');
    $('.sub3 img').css('mix-blend-mode', 'luminosity');
  }, function() {
    $('.sub3').css('color', '');
    $('.sub3 img').css('mix-blend-mode', '');
  });
});
```

Comment: to acces the current element you can use $(this).

Comment: Can you share some of your `HTML` too please? Do you have multiple elements that share the same `class` name?

Comment: It's time to look at using look-up tables and loops. This doesn't need to be a sprawling mass of code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SethMcClaine Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @AndrewElliott There is a specific filter for this this in the close flag, but it doesn't include CR. Stack is not for CR's so it is Off Topic

Answer (score 2):

Select multiple elements at once and figure out which element fired the event with the `target` property of the event argument, or with `this` — either way can be used in any event callback:

```
$(".main1, .main2, .main3, .sub1, .sub2, .sub3").hover(function(e){
  // This function uses `e.target`
  $(e.target).css("color", "#0000d2")
    .find("img").css("mix-blend-mode", "luminosity");
}, function(){
  // This function uses `this`
  $(this).css("color", "")
    .find("img").css("mix-blend-mode", "");
});
```

Though, a better way would be to do all the things in CSS:

```css
.main1:hover,
.main2:hover,
.main3:hover,
.sub1:hover,
.sub2:hover,
.sub3:hover{
  color: #0000d2;
}

.main1:hover img,
.main2:hover img,
.main3:hover img,
.sub1:hover img,
.sub2:hover img,
.sub3:hover img{
  mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
}
```

And then, why not give all elements having those six classes a *common* class, like `img-luminosity`? Then everything would look like this:

```css
.img-luminosity:hover{
  color: #0000d2;
}

.img-luminosity:hover img{
  mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
}
```

Comment: Definitely the best of the given answers

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I am not very good with js and had a pure css-solution before that used something like "header .linkwrapper:hover > .imgwrapper img" to change different styles all at once. 
but since I need to use a grid-based construction for layout-reasons now I cannot use an enclosing element like .linkwrapper any more. therefor I looked for a js-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Might use a simple loop:

```
 for(const s of [".main1", ".main2", ".main3", ".sub1", ".sub2", ".sub3"]) {
   $(s).hover(function() {
    $(s).css('color', '#0000d2');
    $(s + ' img').css('mix-blend-mode', 'luminosity');
   }, function() {
     $(s).css('color', '');
     $(s + ' img').css('mix-blend-mode', '');
   });
 }
```

Comment: No need to continue to wrap `s` in a jQuery object. You can do it once at the top of the loop and use `.find("img")` to get the img children

Comment: You can also simplify this to say `$(".main1, .main2, ...").hover(function () {...})`, there is no need for the array or loop

Comment: @mhodges that doesn't necessarily do the same thing

Comment: How do you figure?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I'll try your solution out right away. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To acces the current element you can use $(this).

```
$('.main1, .main2, .main3, .sub1, .sub2, .sub3').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', '#0000d2');
    $(this).find('img').css('mix-blend-mode', 'luminosity');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('color', '');
    $(this).find('img').css('mix-blend-mode', '');
});
```

you can also add a class to each and use this simple class

```
$('.hoverable').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', '#0000d2');
    $(this).find('img').css('mix-blend-mode', 'luminosity');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('color', '');
    $(this).find('img').css('mix-blend-mode', '');
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I tried something similar after searching stackoverflow several times and looking at different approaches - but none of them worked for my case. I'll your solution out right away. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just combine all the selectors together and use `this` for the hovered element and `find()` for it's image

Then since hover with only one function argument fires for both enter and leave you can simply check the type and adjust values accordingly using the same callback for both

```
$('.main1,.main2, .main3, .sub1').hover(function(event) {
    var isEnter = event.type ==='mouseenter';
    $(this).css('color', isEnter ? '#0000d2' : '')
           .find('img').css('mix-blend-mode', isEnter ? 'luminosity' : '');
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I tried something similar after searching stackoverflow several times and looking at different approaches - but none of them worked for my case. I'll try your solution out right away. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I use for your example ES6 syntax. I hope it would like :)

```js
const style = (el = {}, parameters = {}) => {
  const { colors, mixBlend } = parameters;
  const {base, baseImg} = el;
  
  $(base).css('color', `${colors}`);
  $(baseImg).css('mix-blend-mode', `${mixBlend}`);
}

const el = {
  base: $('.main1'),
  baseImg: $('.main1 img')
}
const styleHover = {
  colors: '#0000d2',
  mixBlend: 'luminosity'
}

const mouseLeave = {
  colors: '',
  mixBlend: ''
}

const hover = () => {
  style(el, styleHover);
}
const mouseleave = () => {
  style(el, mouseLeave);
}


$(function() {
    // 1. Main
    $('.main1').hover(() => hover), () => mouseleave()});
   });
```

Comment: the OP didn't add the tag [tag:ecmascript-6] so it would be wise not to use es-6 syntax unless it was requested... perhaps the OP needs to support browsers that don't support it...